# User Profile Image not showing correctly

Tags: media

I want to show the profile and few content fields for a user profile. For this, I have used views module. Now the problem is that when I select imagecache preset to profile image(which I have defined as 150x200), the output is pathetic. It shows the profile images of around 63x63 size. I thought that the imagecache module might not be working. So I uninstalled and reinstalled the image and imagecache modules, but all in vain. Then I thought of checking into the imagecache folder whether the images are being resized, and to my amazement , the images inside sites/default/files/imagecache/profile_image/pictures/ folder were all of the dimension defined by me for profile image i.e 150x200 . So the problem seems to be only while these images are shown on the frontend.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to this link 
 your_url/admin/config/people/accounts

here you will see 
 field 
 "Picture upload dimensions"
  do not write any dimension in this field , save it and then add profile picture for user

this works in Drupal 7